# Powermock compatibilities

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, powermock

I've been working on some tests that have complex static methods, so I'm using powermock to mock them in my tests.

My config was

- Junit 4.11
- Mockito 1.95
- PowerMock 1.5.6

Everything worked fine until the application upgraded junit from 4.11 to 4.12. This error is shown now where ever I'm using powermock:

> Field 'fTestClass' was not found in class org.junit.internal.runners.MethodValidator.

So I did some research and this problem was fixed in later releases of powermock and, in fact, it doesn't throw me that error when I went to 1.6.6 (nor 1.6.2+). But then something else is breaking:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/internal/creation/util/MockitoMethodProxy

I already had this problem before, I tried with many versions to make it work until I came to the config I mention before ( Junit 4.11, Mockito 1.95, PowerMock 1.5.6).
 The online link I found where version compatibility is documented is here

https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage

But it only talks about mockito with powermock. I tried to combine versions (following the rules for mockito and powermock). I cannot change junit version, so I changed mokito to 2.0.0 and powermock 1.6.6 (as it the doc says it works), but the error persist. I tried 2.5.4 and 1.6.6, and with other versions of powermock. So far, I have not had any luck.

Does anyone know how to config this? Is there any doc about these compatibilities I'm missing?

Comment: Is it `maven` based project?

Comment: That is one of the problems with powermock: far too often you ran exactly into such problems. So if you have a choice, consider spending your time on improving your code under test (by getting rid of that "complex static stuff" which for sure is not the result of a good design in the first place).

Comment: Yes, it is a maven project. Unfortunately, a refactor is not an option right now

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use PowerMock with his Mockito and Junit4 version from the PowerMock repository to have the maximun compatibility from here:

Junit4:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4

Mockito:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2

try to use the same version like this:

gradle example:

`testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.5'
testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.5'`

that worked for me!